# Complex Borel measures: relation between the total variation norm of a measure and those of its real and imaginary parts

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and $\mathcal B$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. For $B \in \mathcal B$ we denote by $\Pi(B)$ the collection of all finite measurable partitions of $B$, i.e.,
$$
\Pi(B)=\left\{\left(B_{1}, \ldots, B_{n}\right) \,\middle\vert\, n \in \mathbb{N^*}, B_{i} \in \mathcal B, B_{i} \cap B_{j}=\varnothing \text { for } 1 \leq i \neq j \leq n, \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B_{i}=B\right\} .
$$

Let $\mu$ be a complex Borel measure on $X$. The variation $|\mu|$ of $\mu$ is defined by
$$
|\mu|(B) := \sup \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|\mu\left(B_{i}\right)\right| \,\middle\vert\, \left(B_{1}, \ldots, B_{n}\right) \in \Pi(B)\right\} \quad \forall B \in \mathcal B.
$$

Let $[\mu] :=|\mu|(X)$ be the total variation norm of $\mu$. Let $\mu_1, \mu_2$ be the real and imaginary parts of $\mu$ respectively, i.e., $\mu = \mu_1 + i\mu_2$. Then $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are finite signed Borel measures on $X$. So for each $B \in \mathcal B$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
|\mu|(B) &= \sup \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{|\mu_1(B_{i})|^2 + |\mu_2(B_{i})|^2} \,\middle\vert\, \left(B_{1}, \ldots, B_{n}\right) \in \Pi(B)\right\} \\
&\le \sup \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (|\mu_1(B_{i})| + |\mu_2(B_{i})|) \,\middle\vert\, \left(B_{1}, \ldots, B_{n}\right) \in \Pi(B)\right\} \\
&\le \sup \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\mu_1(B_i)| \,\middle\vert\, \left(B_{1}, \ldots, B_{n}\right) \in \Pi(B)\right\} \\
&\quad + \sup \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\mu_2(B_i)| \,\middle\vert\, \left(B_{1}, \ldots, B_{n}\right) \in \Pi(B)\right\} \\
&= |\mu_1| (B) + \mu_2(B).
\end{align}
$$

As such, $|\mu| \le |\mu_1| + |\mu_2|$. In particular, $[\mu] \le [\mu_1] + [\mu_2]$.

> I would like to ask if either $|\mu| \ge |\mu_1| + |\mu_2|$ or $[\mu] \ge [\mu_1] + [\mu_2]$ is true.

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

---

**Update:** Let's define a new variation on the space of complex Borel measures on $X$.

- For a finite signed Borel measure $\mu$, its new variation is $|\mu|' := |\mu|$.
- For a complex Borel measure $\mu = \mu_1 + i\mu_2$ with $\mu_1, \mu_2$ being its real and imaginary parts, its new variation is $|\mu|' := |\mu_1| + |\mu_2|$.

Then for any complex Borel measure $\mu$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2} |\mu|' \le |\mu| \le |\mu|'.
$$

We define $[\mu]':= |\mu|' (X)$. Then $[\cdot]'$ is a norm on the space of complex Borel measures such that
$$
\frac{1}{2} [\cdot]' \le [\cdot] \le [\cdot]'.
$$

It follows that

- $|\mu|' = |\mu_1|' + |\mu_2|'$ and thus $[\mu]' = [\mu_1]' + [\mu_2]'$ for every complex Borel measure $\mu$ whose real and imaginary parts are $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ respectively.
- $[\cdot]$ and $[\cdot]'$ are [equivalent norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Equivalent_norms) on the space of complex Borel measures.
- $[\cdot]$ and $[\cdot]'$ coincide on the subspace of finite signed Borel measures.

Comment: If I'm correct, $X$ is just a metrizable space, the choice of a distance playing no role.

Comment: @YCor Yeah I don't see we use any property of the metric here.

Comment: Let $X=[0,1]$ and let $m$ be Lebesgue measure. Take $\mu = m+im$.

Comment: @NikWeaver Could you please have a check if my update is fine?

Comment: Looks good. I guess the $\frac{1}{2}$ can be improved to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @NikWeaver Thank you so much for your confirm!

Comment: @NikWeaver Could you explain how to get the improved constant $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: For any complex number $z = x + iy$ we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x| +|y|) \leq |z| \leq |x|+|y|$.

Comment: @NikWeaver I may be wrong, but $\sup_{a \in A} (f(a) + g(a))$ is *not* necessarily bigger than $\left ( \sup_{a \in A} f(a)  + \sup_{a \in A} g(a) \right )$. So I'm still not clear how you get the improved constant.

Comment: That is true, but why don't you think about this a little more on your own?

Comment: @NikWeaver Could you have a check on my below answer?

Comment: Looks fine. It might be easier to work with the Radon-Nikodym derivative $f = \frac{d\mu}{d|\mu|}$. Writing $f = f_1 + if_2$, we get $[\mu] = \int |f|\, d|\mu|$ and $[\mu]' = \int (|f_1| + |f_2|)\, d|\mu|$.

Comment: @NikWeaver Thank you so much for your verification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I represent below @NikWeaver's idea of improving $\frac{1}{2} [\cdot]' \le [\cdot]$ to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} [\cdot]' \le [\cdot]$.

---

For complex number $z = x + iy$ with $x,y \in \mathbb R$, we have
$$
|z| \ge \frac{|x| +|y|}{\sqrt{2}} .
$$

Fix a Borel subset $B$ of $X$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
|\mu|(B) &= \sup \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{|\mu_1(B_{i})|^2 + |\mu_2(B_{i})|^2} \,\middle\vert\, \left(B_{1}, \ldots, B_{n}\right) \in \Pi(B)\right\} \\
&\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \sup \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\mu_1(B_{i})| + |\mu_2(B_{i})| \,\middle\vert\, \left(B_{1}, \ldots, B_{n}\right) \in \Pi(B)\right\}.
\end{align}
$$

It remains to prove that
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sup \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\mu_1(B_{i})| + |\mu_2(B_{i})| \,\middle\vert\, (B_{1}, \ldots, B_{n}) \in \Pi(B)\right\} \\
= & \sup \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\mu_1(B_{i})| \,\middle\vert\, (B_{1}, \ldots, B_{n}) \in \Pi(B) \right\} + \sup \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\mu_2(B_{i})| \,\middle\vert\, (B_{1}, \ldots, B_{n}) \in \Pi(B) \right\}.
\end{aligned}
$$

The direction $\le$ is obvious. Let's prove the reverse $\ge$. For each $n$, let

- $(B_{1,1}, \ldots, B_{1, \varphi_n}) \in \Pi(B)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\varphi_n} |\mu_1(B_{1, i})| \nearrow |\mu_1| (B)$.
- $(B_{2,1}, \ldots, B_{2, \psi_n}) \in \Pi(B)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\psi_n} |\mu_2(B_{2, i})| \nearrow |\mu_2| (B)$.
- $(B_{3, 1}, \ldots, B_{3, \lambda_n}) :=\{B_{1, i} \cap B_{2, j} \mid i = 1, \ldots, \varphi_n \text{ and } j = 1, \ldots, \psi_n\} \in \Pi(B)$.

Then $(B_{3, 1}, \ldots, B_{3, \lambda_n}) \in B$ is finer than both $(B_{1,1}, \ldots, B_{1, \varphi_n})$ and $(B_{2,1}, \ldots, B_{2, \psi_n})$. By triangle inequality, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\varphi_n} |\mu_1(B_{1, i})| \le \sum_{i=1}^{\lambda_n} |\mu_1(B_{3, i})|
\quad \text{and} \quad 
\sum_{i=1}^{\psi_n} |\mu_2(B_{2, i})| \le \sum_{i=1}^{\lambda_n} |\mu_2(B_{3, i})|.
$$

It follows that
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^{\lambda_n} |\mu_1(B_{3,i})| + |\mu_2(B_{3,i})| \ge \sum_{i=1}^{\varphi_n} |\mu_1(B_{1, i})|  + \sum_{i=1}^{\psi_n} |\mu_2(B_{2, i})| .
$$

The claim then follows.